# wp_handle_upload uploads multiple sizes for each image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file-upload

I am trying to create a file upload function in a wordpress plugin, that allows a user to upload one file, which will later be displayed as a sort of thumbnail. The code i used looks like this:

```php
$file_return = wp_handle_upload($logo, array('test_form' => false));
if (isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])) {
    return false;
} else {
    $filename = $file_return['file'];

    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'guid' => $file_return['url']
    );

    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_return['file']);

    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $filename);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
    if (0 < intval($attachment_id)) {
        return $attachment_id;
    }
}
```

And the html is simple:

```html
<form ...>
    <input type='file' name='logo-upload' id='logo-upload'>
</form>
```

Also the JS for uploading the logo through AJAX: (jquery)

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var logo = $('#logo-upload')[0].files[0];
formData.append('logo', logo);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '...',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('uploaded!');
    alert(data);
});
```

This is not all the code but I believe it is all that is relevant. 
The problem here is that instead of only one file, with the name say `image.png` being uploaded, I get this:

`image.png`
`image-150x150.png`
`image-300x179.png`
`image-410x121.png`
`...`
I know wordpress does this by default, but is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

In Media settings (Settings -> Media )  you can try to put all the sizes listed over there to 0 (zero) on width and height. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP filters. Function unset() destroys the specified variables:

```
    add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'prefix_remove_default_images' );
// Remove default image sizes here. 
function prefix_remove_default_images( $sizes ) {
 unset( $sizes['small']); // 150px
 unset( $sizes['medium']); // 300px
 unset( $sizes['large']); // 1024px
 unset( $sizes['medium_large']); // 768px
 return $sizes;
}
```